# Converting a List to 2d array and then back - java

Tags: java, arrays, list, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a List to a 2d array and then after I do some operations on the 2d array, I want to convert it back to a List in the initial order. I've been working to much on this program and now I'm completely blind to what I'm missing, but the result of the last method does not match the initial list at all.

The Method I used for converting the List into a 2d array is the following:

```
public static Map<String, long[][]> convertListToMatrix(List<YUV> yuvList, int width, int height) {
    Map<String, long[][]> imageMatrix = new HashMap<String, long[][]>();
    long[][] yMatrix = new long[height][width];
    long[][] uMatrix = new long[height][width];
    long[][] vMatrix = new long[height][width];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            YUV yuvPixel = yuvList.get((j * height) + i);
            yMatrix[i][j] = yuvPixel.getY();
            uMatrix[i][j] = yuvPixel.getU();
            vMatrix[i][j] = yuvPixel.getV();
        }
    }
    imageMatrix.put("y", yMatrix);
    imageMatrix.put("u", uMatrix);
    imageMatrix.put("v", vMatrix);
    return imageMatrix;
}
```

For Matrix to list I use this:

```
public static List<YUV> convertMatrixToYUVList(long[][] yMatrix, long[][] uMatrix, long[][] vMatrix, int width, int height) {
    List<YUV> yuvList = new ArrayList<YUV>();
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            yuvList.add(new YUV(yMatrix[i][j], uMatrix[i][j], vMatrix[i][j]));
    return yuvList;
}
```

Can anyone see how I'm going wrong at this?

Comment: what is the logic of converting a List to a 2d array?

Comment: I simply need it as a 2d array as input for other methods I'm using.

Comment: can you please provide an input and output values? this is really unclear

Comment: Sorry, it's late here and I'm a bit tired. Yeah, I should have given more information. The first method is taking as input a List of YUV (which is a class that consists of 3 long attributes (y, v and u). By running the first method, I'm trying to convert that list into 3 x 2d array of width x height dimensions for each of the attribute (so a 2d array for y, a 2d array for u and a 2d array for u).

Comment: The second method, I want to recreate the initial list by creating the YUV object from the 2d arrays and adding it to the list. The important thing is that after both methods, I need to have the output List of the second method exactly the same as the input List of the first one.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're doing, but I can help you with the logic behind converting from list to 2d array and back.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great

Comment: Okay, so here is the gist of the logic, tell me if it's confusing.

Comment: For list to array: 1. object array = new object[square_root_of_list.size()][square_root_of_list.size()]; 2. for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 3. for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) 4. array[i][j] = list.remove(0);

Comment: For array to list: 1. List<Object> = new List<Object>(); 2. for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) 3. for(int j = 0; j<array[0].length; j++) 4. list.add(0,array[i][j]);

Comment: I think the main problem is that you were getting objects from the beginning of the list, then adding them to the end, causing your list to become reversed after being changed.

Comment: Thanks, I did it your way and it works, but the `list.remove(0);` works a bit slow. I eventually managed to fix my code, the problem was in the first method, more exactly here `j * height) + i`. Just declared a new int to act as a count for the current element of the list and used it in the list.get(); and now it works. Thank you for your time.